# Why does disabling depth test on iOS *delete* already-rendered geometry from the scene

Tags: ios, opengl-es

This makes no sense to me, but it's confirmed with both Apple iOS 7.x simulator and iOS 6.x on devices:

Setup 1:

1. clear
2. disable DEPTH_TEST
3. draw a fullscreen quad
4. enable DEPTH_TEST
5. draw lots of geometry
6. draw a quad

...everything is rendered

Setup 2:

1. clear
2. disable DEPTH_TEST
3. draw a fullscreen quad
4. enable DEPTH_TEST
5. draw lots of geometry
6. disable DEPTH_TEST
7. draw a quad

...only the FIRST and LAST items are rendered

---

Confirmed using Apple's "Analyze Frame" tool, that shows everything being rendered, but once DEPTH is disabled, Analyze Frame shows the middle drawcalls firing, writng, and yet NO EFFECT on the RenderBuffer.

Also: I tried replacing "disable DEPTH_TEST" with "enable DEPTH_TEST, but set glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS)". No surprise - everything renders again.

---

What's going on? The OpenGL documentation makes no mention of this "stuff you've rendered will magically disappear"

Comment: Disabling DEPTH_TEST very much disables depth-writes - check out the docs for glDisable(). But I'll correct the text to be clearer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! Re-reading the question ... it's that sneaky old design feature in the API:

> If DEPTH_TEST is disabled, glClear is redefined to do something
>   different from normal (it ignores the DEPTH bit) - with no errors
>   reported.

Looking at my setup ... DEPTH_TEST is still disabled from the end of the previous frame, so on all frames after the first, the depth buffer won't clear.

ALSO: I checked Apple's frame analyzer, and realised I was mis-reading it. Apple shows "black" to mean "full" and "white" to mean "empty" (I thought it was the other way around). So ... the depth buffer was showing as "never being cleared", but I was foolishly misinterpreting it. In fact, only the calls that disable depth were getting through.